# How can I return a pointer to a non C Compatible struct from rust code to C code?

Tags: rust, ffi

I have a rust struct whose pointer I need to return to the C code ? The struct is not C compatible.
Is there anyway I can just return a pointer to this struct and pass the pointer in a subsequent call.

```
struct abc
{
  pub a : ObjectType
   
}
```

I want to define a function that returns a pointer to this struct

```
[no_mangle] 
pub extern "C" fn GetPointer(params: Params) -> * abc
```

and then use the pointer returned in a subsequent call

```
[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn UseStructPointer(pointer : * abc, params: Params)
```

I see all the examples on the internet return a pointer to a struct which is C compatible.

Comment: It is unclear what the function `GetPointer` is supposed to do. Should it create a new value of type `abc`? Have you tried following the [Rust FFI Omnibus on Objects](https://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/objects/)? Those declarations are not syntactically valid: missing `#` before `[no_mangle]` and `const` or `mut` before `*` to describe raw pointer types.

Comment: This is a good resource on the topic: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html#representing-opaque-structs

Comment: You can send a pointer to a regular Rust struct to C and retrieve it exactly the same way as for a C struct. The only difference is that you won't be able to access the struct fields from C (so you will need to use a `void*` pointer in the C code).

Comment: Can you point me to some example code ?